# Web Add-In no longer visible under "My Organization"

Tags: excel, ms-office, office365

I deployed my add-in using the following method: [centralized deployment](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment). Since the retirement of NapaCloud, I am not able to see my Web Add-In from Excel desktop. I now get a "Cannot connect to catalog" error message and can see that it is trying to reach out to NapaCloud to connect to the catalog.

So, how do I deploy a Web Add-In through Office365 so that I can see the Add-In on Excel Desktop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the Add-In and try uploading it again. The issue is now resolved

Comment: I can now see it on Excel Desktop but it is not there in Excel Online. Thanks Phil.